# Getting an error while using the atan2() function on two Eigen matrices

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am new to Eigen, and am trying to use the atan2() function on the 2nd and 3rd columns of the inputMatrix.
The atan2 function is underlined red, telling me "class Eigen::Matrix has no member "atan2""
, I receive a different error if I try:
atan2(Z)
-or-

```
atan2(A.array(), B.array())
```

Again, being new to Eigen, my understanding is that I need to use .array on the matrix to perform operations but I feel like I did that below. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
Eigen::MatrixXd sampleFunction(Eigen::MatrixXd inputMatrix)
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd Z, A, B, V;

    A = inputMatrix.col(1);
    B = inputMatrix.col(2);

    Z = (A.array(), B.array());
    V = Z.atan2();

    return V;
}
```

Comment: Unless the class provides an `atan2()` method, the `std::atan2` method takes two simple floating-point values and produces a single result.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify there are two different trigonometric functions for tan.

- The `atan2()` calculates all four of the quadrants.
- The `atan()` *only* calculates one and four quadrants.

Now, `eigen` only supports `atan()`. Which computes the arc tangent.

That is why you are getting the error  `"class Eigen::Matrix has no member "atan2""`.

However, using the headerfile `#include <cmath>` or `#include <valarray>` you can use the function `atan2()`. `valarray` also includes `atan2()`.

For example using the headerfile `#include <valarray>`

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <valarray>



int main()
{

    double y[] = { 2.0, 1.6, -3.8, 2.3 };
    double x[] = { 3.0, -2.4, 2.0, -1.8 };


    std::valarray<double> ycoords(y, 4);
    std::valarray<double> xcoords(x, 4);

    //Results go to valarray
    std::valarray<double> res = atan2(ycoords, xcoords);

    // print results of atan2() function 
    std::cout << "results:";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << ' ' << res[i];
    std::cout << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right, thank you for your answer! So, I've included <cmath> and if I now define the function as 'V = atan2(Z)' I see the error: "no instance of overloaded function "atan2" matches the argument list ... argument types are (Eigen::MatrixXd)"

Comment: Yes, I believe so, they're both defined as doubles. ie: MatrixXd produces a dynamic sized matrix of doubles. Then .array is applied to both matrices

Comment: Have you tried `atan()` just to see if your code works?